# how to add t-sql code in visual basic application

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

i had written a code in t-sql that will create a table in sql server and insert data into that by joining two tables already present.
now i am developing a tool in visual basic in which i have to click on a command button and all done.My question is how to add that t-sql code into visul basic command object property text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [SqlCommand.CommandText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext.aspx) property and if you look at this method [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) you'll see how to use it.